# Виджет размером больше, чем QWIDGETSIZE_MAX

Tags: qt

на QScrollArea есть виджет на котором рисуется картинка с помощью qpainter.
Размеры этой картинки должны быть больше QWIDGETSIZE_MAX. Возможно ли это как-нибудь провернуть? стек виджетов?

Answer (score 3):

`QWIDGETSIZE_MAX` на то и **max**.

Используйте [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) и [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) для рисования и отображения большой картинки.